# Wordpress Admin Not Working on AppEngine Subdomain

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, subdirectory

I recently configured a wordpress site to run on google app engine. [Following this to get the site up](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-wordpress-on-appengine-standard). I want the site to be on a subdirectory so I made the following changes:

In wp-config.php

```php
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com/blog');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com/blog');
```

Then I updated the database wp_options table, changing the option_name 'siteurl', 'home' to `https://example.com/blog`

I also changed the app.yaml file and placed `/blog/` infront of all the urls... one example

```
url: /blog/(.*\.(htm|html|css|js))
```

The wordpress site loads and I can navigate through the links, everything looks good on /blog/. The only problem is when I try to go to `/wp-admin` I get a too many redirects error in the browser.

How can configure the admin page to also work on /blog?

One other issue (probably related) is with the `/wp-login` route... which actually does not work on `/blog/wp-login` but does appear on just `/wp-login` this is not what I would expect and want that to be on `/blog/wp-login`.

Where should I go from here?

Comment: I think you need to tweak your `gae-app.php` file. It looks like it tries to derive file name from request url path but can't due to 'blog' prefix. Try removing `/blog` from request url.

Comment: This  fixed it! `$request_uri =  str_replace('/blog', '', @parse_url($full_request_uri)['path']);`